# Error when compiling Private member of class of type vector - C++

Tags: c++, class, vector

I am creating a class for a Minesweeper game. The class does not take any parameters. Private members are initiliazed within the class. My objective to initiliaze a two dimensional vector of ints.

```
using namespace std;

class Minesweeper {
public:
    //This class takes no parameters
    //Other methods will be here

private:
    int rows = 20;
    int cols = 20;
    vector < vector <int>> theBoard(rows, vector<int>(cols));
};
```

The compilation errors I recieve are as follows: (both in the line with the vector initialization)

1. Function definition for "theBoard" not found
2. member "Minesweeper::rows" is not a type name

I do not understand the above errors. I do believe I used the proper syntax in creating the two dimentional vector. Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a constructor to your class.  For instance,

```
class Minesweeper
{
    public:
        Minesweeper()
        : rows(20),
          cols(20),
          theBoard(rows, vector<int>(cols))
        {

        }

    private:
        int rows, cols;

        vector<vector<int>> theBoard;
};
```

Comment: A constructor is not needed here. All members are initialized correctly already.

Comment: @Nikos, `theBoard` is a member variable, not a method.

Comment: This would also work: `vector<vector<int>> theBoard{static_cast<size_t>(rows), vector<int>{cols}};` Which avoids the need to write a ctor.

Answer (score 1):

This is an "MVP" (most vexing parse) example. See the question this has been made a duplicate of for more information on the issue.

However, I'm still giving an answer here on how to correctly initialize `theBoard`, because normally, you'd write this:

```
vector<vector<int>> theBoard{rows, vector<int>{cols}};
```

But this won't work, since when using an initializer list, `rows` can't be implicitly converted to a `size_t`. So you need this instead:

```
vector<vector<int>> theBoard{static_cast<size_t>(rows), vector<int>{cols}};
```

You could change `rows` and `cols` from `int` to `size_t` instead, but it's not recommended to use `size_t` (or unsigned integers in general) for quantities. (`vector` using an unsigned integer for its size is almost a language defect in C++, which can't be fixed now since it would break too much code.)